# Shopware 6 app installation missing Integration

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

we developed an app following the guide:

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/app-base-guide

We successfully tested it with hardcoded secret (dev mode) in the manifest.xml.
We have now removed the dev secret from the manifest and generated a true secret uploading our app.
We received a test store to try it but we have this following issue: whenever we install and activate our app/extension we see on our server that the registration flow is correctly performed and an API key/secret is correctly generated.

When we search from the integration on the Shopware administration panel in "Settings>System>Integrations" no integration is displayed.
We can't understand why.
Any suggestion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the request payload in the administration for the request that fetches the integrations, you can find that integrations of apps are deliberately excluded. So it is intended that integrations associated with apps should not show up there. Check the database table `integration` instead, if you want to verify that your app has in fact created an integration record.

```json
{
   // ...
   "filter":[
      {
         "type": "equals",
         "field": "deletedAt",
         "value": null
      },
      {
         "type": "equals",
         "field": "app.id",
         "value": null // means only integrations without associated apps
      }
   ],
   // ...
}
```

Comment: The integration has been created, I see it in the database. Is there any setting to enable it on integrations panel or should it be pointed in the manifest.xml somehow?

Comment: No, everything is fine. If it's there everything worked and there's no need to act. I'm not a 100% sure why it shouldn't be listed in the administration, but I assume it's because apps have to ask for permissions during the installation and the admin should uninstall the app if they no longer want to grant those permissions. The admin shouldn't be able to alter the permissions, as app developers have to rely on the permissions being granted where their apps are installed.